# Combinatorics problem: probability of picking balls of $K$ different colours

Tags: combinatorics

There is a box with unlimited number of balls of $C$ different colours. Balls of the same colour are indistinguishable. We are picking balls at random with equal probability for each colour. What is the probability of picking $N$ balls out of the box such that there are $K$ balls of specific different colours?

My idea is as follows:

> Select $K$ of $N$ bins - there are $\binom{N}{K}$ ways to do that. Next, we need to place $K$ balls in those places - there are $K!$ ways to do that. After these steps, there are $N - K$ places left empty, and we fill them with balls of any colour - $C^{N - K}$ ways. To obtain the probability we need to divide by total number of sequences - $C^N$. Finally, we have this formula: $\frac{\binom{N}{K} \times K! \times C^{N - K}}{C^N}$.

This formula seems to be wrong.
An example: assume $N = 4$, $C = 4$, $K = 3$. I have programmatically calculated that there are 60 such sequences. So, the probability of getting such a sequence is $\frac{60}{4^4} = \frac{15}{64}$. According to the formula, this should be equal to $\frac{\binom{4}{3} \times 3! \times  4^{4 - 3}}{4^4} = \frac{24}{64}$, which is wrong.

Comment: Do you want exactly $K$ of each of the colors or at least $K$?  Do you care about the order of the draws, or just the quantity of each color?  How many colors are there $K$ of?  Until you write a specific question it is impossible to answer

Comment: @RossMillikan I want balls of $K$ specific colours to be present in the set of $N$ selected balls, i.e. order doesn't matter. There are $C$ colours overall.

Comment: Do you want just one ball of each of the $K$ colors?  Then when you choose the $K$ colors there is only one way to draw one ball of each.  You then have to compute the number of ways to draw $N-K$ balls of $C-K$ colors.  This is a stars and bars problem.

Comment: @RossMillikan Why $C - K$? I have an infinite amount of balls per each colour.

Comment: So you can have more than one ball of the $K$ colors?

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes. Sorry, If this was unclear. I have $K$ selected colours, balls of which I want to see in my set of $N$ selected balls. I can pick any amount of balls of each colour - hence the unlimited amount of balls of all colours in the box. The amount of selected balls of specific colour doesn't matter, it just has to be present in the set.

Comment: You must resume your **pieces** of clarifications in editing your post, and adding an example. Thanks

Comment: @GCab Thanks for the heads-up. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two counting errors in your attempt.

Consider your example, $N = 4$, $C = 4$, $K = 3$. Let the four colors be $\{b,g,r,y\}$ and the three selected colors be $\{b,g,r\}.$
Select $3$ of $4$ bins: $1,2,3.$ Place three balls of the selected colors in those bins: $1\to b,\ 2\to g,\ 3\to r.$ Place a ball of any color in the remaining bin (bin number $4$); suppose we pick the color $b.$ So we have the following colors of balls in the four bins:
$$1\to b,\ 2\to g,\ 3\to r,\ 4\to b.$$

Now select a *different* subset of $3$ of the $4$ bins: $2,3,4.$ Place three balls of the selected colors in those bins: $2\to g,\ 3\to r,\ 4\to b.$ Place a ball of any color in the remaining bin (bin number $1$); suppose we pick the color $b.$ Then we have the following colors of balls in the four bins:
$$1\to b,\ 2\to g,\ 3\to r,\ 4\to b.$$

Notice that it's the exact same sequence of colors each time. But we generated the sequences in two different ways, and your verbal description counts them as two sequences.

On the other hand, you count $(N-K)^C$ ways to fill $N-K$ spaces with balls of $C$ different possible colors. The correct number of possibilities for that action is $C^{N-K},$ which comes out to $4$ rather than $1$ in your example. That is, applying your verbal description of the count accurately, you would compute the probability $\frac{96}{4^4} = \frac{24}{4^4}.$

In summary, you start with a method that overcounts, but then you apply a formula incorrectly and thereby undercount one of the steps of your method by a factor of $4,$ and you end up with too low a probability in the end.

---

To do the actual probability, you might start by calculating the probability that a particular color is missing from the $N$ random balls, then find the probability that at least one of your $K$ selected colors is missing. But then (I think) you would have to do an inclusion-exclusion process to avoid excluding the various combinations of two colors, three colors, etc., too many times or too few times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been using the right formula in my program, but have typed in it the other way around in the question. Of course, you're right, my approach is flawed nonetheless. One of the answers suggested using compositions (when the question was posed differently), could they be applied in some way to calculate this? Or inclusion-exclusion principle is the only way?

Comment: The problem with compositions is that they're not equally likely, so you cannot just divide one count by another. You might have to divide your problem into a large number of sub-cases, with the number of sub-cases depending on $N,$ $C$, and $K.$

Comment: I've used inclusion-exclusion principle, seems to be working well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing there is no constraint on the number of balls in the box, the number of ways to pick N balls with at least K colors is infinite.

Comment: That may technically be true but the problem almost certainly assumes that balls of the same color are indistinguishable. This is drawing with replacement.

Comment: The number of balls in the box is infinite for each colour, but we are picking only $N$ of them.

Comment: The problem as worded is asking how many ways to pick N balls from an infinite set. If the interpretation is for equal probability of picking from C colors, then what is the number of ways to select a set N with at least K colors, then it needs to state that. I didn't give it a down vote but that's probably why it got them.

Comment: @PhilH Well, neither English is my first language, nor I am well versed in mathematics, but I gave my best. Thanks for patience :).

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the number of [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $N$ into $C$ parts.  $K$ of those parts are required to have at least one item, the remaining $C-K$ can have zero.  Add one ball of the $C-K$ colors and ask about compositions of $N+C-K$ into $C$ parts where every part has to be at least $1$.  This is a classic [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem which has ${N+C-K-1 \choose C-1}$ possibilities.

Comment: Thanks. If I need to determine the probability of picking $N$ balls, $K$ of which have specific colours (the rest could have any colour), I need to divide $\binom{N + C - K - 1}{C - 1}$ by $\binom{N + C - 1}{C - 1}$?

Comment: You need to specify how you pick the balls. Your denominator is the number of compositions but they are not equally probable.

Comment: I pick balls at random with equal probability for each colour.

Comment: Consider $N=C=2$. There are three compositions. The one with the balls different is twice as likely as the others

Comment: How should I approach the problem if I want to calculate the probability?

Comment: @RossMillikan: If you use the *(weak) compositions of N into C parts* then you are **disregarding the order** in which  the color are extracted, isn't it ? but  in the extractions the order does matter (the equi-probable space is $c^n$ in fact).

Comment: @GCab This answer was written before I clarified my question.

Comment: @AndrewVershinin: I see, ok.

Answer (score 0):

Let me use lower case characters  to keep the notation cleaner, and let me replace $K$ with $m$ to keep $k$ as a variable index.
So
*from a pool of balls with $c$ different colors, $n$ balls extracted, out of which "$m$ balls with specific different colors"*;
or
*from the alphabet $\{1,2,\cdots,c\}$, words of length $n$ containing "$m$  specific different characters"*.

In the comments, me and others, tried to warn that the expression in ".." is not well specified.
I will try some possible interpretations.

Start with
$$
\left( {p_{\,1}  + p_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + p_{\,c} } \right) = 1
$$
where in this case $p_1=p_2=\cdots=p_c=1/c$.

Then
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\begin{array}{l}
 1 = \left( {p_{\,1}  + p_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + p_{\,c} } \right)^{\,n}  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {0\, \le \,k_{\,j} \, \le \,n}  \\
   {k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \, \cdots  + k_{\,c} \, = \,n}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\;} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n \\ 
 k_{\,1} ,k_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,k_{\,c}  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)p_{\,1} ^{\,k_{\,1} } p_{\,2} ^{\,k_{\,2} }  \cdots p_{\,c} ^{\,k_{\,c} } }  \\ 
 \end{array}
} \tag{1}$$
where the multinomial coefficient give the number of ways of having $k_1$ repetitions of color 1, $k_2$ of color 2, etc.
irrespective of the order, out of $c^n$ total possible extractions (words of length $n$).

Now, if you want that
*the $n$ extracted balls be of* **exactly** $m$ **specified** *colors*
since the colors are equi-probable we can assume them to be colors $1,2,\cdots,m$, therefore
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 P(m,n)\quad \left| {\;m \le n} \right.\quad  = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {1\, \le \,k_{\,j} \,\left( { \le \,n} \right)}  \\   {k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \, \cdots  + k_{\,m} \, = \,n}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\;} {\frac{{n!}}{{k_{\,1} !k_{\,2} !\, \cdots k_{\,m} !}}p_{\,1} ^{\,k_{\,1} } p_{\,2} ^{\,k_{\,2} }  \cdots p_{\,m} ^{\,k_{\,m} } }  =  \\ 
  = \left( {p_{\,1} p_{\,2}  \cdots p_{\,m} } \right)\sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {0\, \le \,l_{\,j} \,\left( { \le \,n - m} \right)}  \\   {l_{\,1}  + l_{\,2}  + \, \cdots  + l_{\,m} \, = \,n - m}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\;} {\frac{{n!}}{{\left( {l_{\,1}  + 1} \right)!\left( {l_{\,2}  + 1} \right)!\, \cdots \left( {l_{\,m}  + 1} \right)!}}
p_{\,1} ^{\,l_{\,1} } p_{\,2} ^{\,l_{\,2} }  \cdots p_{\,m} ^{\,l_{\,m} } }  =  \\ 
  = \frac{{n!}}{{\left( {n - m} \right)!}}\left( {p_{\,1} p_{\,2}  \cdots p_{\,m} } \right)\sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {0\, \le \,l_{\,j} \,\left( { \le \,n - m} \right)}  \\   {l_{\,1}  + l_{\,2}  + \, \cdots  + l_{\,m} \, = \,n - m}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\;} {\frac{1}{{\left( {l_{\,1}  + 1} \right)\left( {l_{\,2}  + 1} \right)\, \cdots \left( {l_{\,m}  + 1} \right)}}\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n - m \\  l_{\,1} ,l_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,l_{\,m}  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)p_{\,1} ^{\,l_{\,1} } p_{\,2} ^{\,l_{\,2} }  \cdots p_{\,m} ^{\,l_{\,m} } }  \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
which for constant probabilities $p_1=p_2=\cdots=p_m=1/c$ gives
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
P(m,n)\quad \left| {\;m \le n} \right.\quad  = \frac{{n!}}{{\left( {n - m} \right)!}}c^{\, - \,n} \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {0\, \le \,l_{\,j} \,\left( { \le \,n - m} \right)}  \\
   {l_{\,1}  + l_{\,2}  + \, \cdots  + l_{\,m} \, = \,n - m}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\;} {\frac{1}{{\left( {l_{\,1}  + 1} \right)\left( {l_{\,2}  + 1} \right)\, \cdots \left( {l_{\,m}  + 1} \right)}}\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n - m \\ 
 l_{\,1} ,l_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,l_{\,m}  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)} 
} \tag{2}$$

We have better to take it from the Cumulative side, i.e.
*the $n$ extracted balls consist of* **up to** *$m$* **specified** *colors*
that is, we admit that some of the wanted colors may be absent. Then
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 Q(m,n) = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {0\, \le \,k_{\,j} \,\left( { \le \,n} \right)}  \\   {k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \, \cdots  + k_{\,m} \, = \,n}  \\
\end{array}} \right.\;} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n \\  k_{\,1} ,k_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,k_{\,m}  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)p_{\,1} ^{\,k_{\,1} } p_{\,2} ^{\,k_{\,2} }  \cdots p_{\,m} ^{\,k_{\,m} } }  =  \\ 
  = \left( {p_{\,1}  + p_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + p_{\,m} } \right)^{\,n}  = \left( {\frac{m}{c}} \right)^{\,n} \quad \left| \begin{array}{l}
 \;\left( {m \le n} \right) \\ 
 \;0 \le m \le c \\ 
 \end{array} \right.\quad  \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
which is obvious.

After which we can write that
$$
Q(m,n) = {1 \over {c^{\,n} }}m^{\,n}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {
 \binom{m}{k}
 P(k,n)} 
$$
because there are $\binom{m}{k}$ ways to choose the $k$ colors to be present, out of $m$.

According to [Binomial Inversion theorem] we can invert the above as:
$$
P(m,n) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m - k} 
\binom {m}{k}   Q(k,n)}
  = {1 \over {c^{\,n} }}\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m - k} 
  \binom {m}{k}   k^{\,n} 
 } 
$$
and using this definition of [Stirling Numbers of the 2nd kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)
$$
\left\{ \matrix{  n \cr m \cr}  \right\}\quad
    = {1 \over {m!}}\sum\limits_k {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m - k} \binom {m}{k}  k^{\,n} } 
$$

we finally get
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
P(m,n) = {1 \over {c^{\,n} }}m!\left\{ \matrix{n \cr m \cr}  \right\}
} \tag{3}$$

In fact, the combinatorial interpretation of the Stirling Numbers of 2nd kind gives that
 - $\left\{ \matrix{n \cr m \cr}  \right\}$ is the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ labelled objects into $m$ nonempty **unlabelled** subsets;
 - $m! \left\{ \matrix{n \cr m \cr}  \right\}$ is the number of surjections from a $|n|$-set into a $|m|$-set.

And the last is just another way to express your question, under the considered interpretation.
In fact identity (3) matches with (2).

If instead the interpretation is
*the $n$ extracted balls consist of* **exactly** *$m$* **distinct** *colors (whichever, out of the $c$ available)*
then clearly
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
R(m,n) = {1 \over {c^{\,n} }}\left( \matrix{  c \cr   m \cr}  \right) m!
  \left\{ \matrix{ n \cr   m \cr}  \right\} 
 = {1 \over {c^{\,n} }}  \left\{ \matrix{ n \cr  m \cr}  \right\} 
c^{\,\underline {\,m\,} } 
}\tag{4} $$

Now, for your example with $N=n=4\; C=c=4$ and with $K=m=0,1,2,3,4$ the above give
$$
\eqalign{
  & P(m,4)\quad \left| {\;m = 0 \cdots 4} \right.\quad  = {1 \over {4^{\,4} }}\left( {0,\;1,\;14,\;36,\;24} \right)  \cr 
  & R(m,4)\quad \left| {\;m = 0 \cdots 4} \right.\quad  = {1 \over {4^{\,4} }}\left( {0,\;4,\;84,\;144,\;24} \right) \cr} 
$$
and in fact 
$$
\eqalign{
  & P(2,4) = \mathop {\left( \matrix{
  4 \cr 
  1 \cr}  \right)}\limits_{\left( {a,b,b,b} \right)}  + \mathop {\left( \matrix{
  4 \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right)}\limits_{\left( {a,a,b,b} \right)}  + \mathop {\left( \matrix{
  4 \cr 
  3 \cr}  \right)}\limits_{\left( {a,a,a,b} \right)}  = 2^{\,4}  - 2 = 14  \cr 
  & P(3,4) = \mathop {{{4!} \over {2!}}}\limits_{\left( {a,b,c,a} \right)}  + \mathop {{{4!} \over {2!}}}\limits_{\left( {a,b,c,b} \right)}  + \mathop {{{4!} \over {2!}}}\limits_{\left( {a,b,c,c} \right)}  = 12 \cdot 3 = 36 \cr} 
$$

I checked (3) and (4) brute force for small values.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer, I've got to learn a lot from it! Let me give it another try based on your first interpretation : _What is the probability of picking a random word of length $n$ from the alphabet $\{1,2,⋯,c\}$ (with equal probability) that it contains all symbols $ \{1,2,...,m\}$._

Comment: @AndrewVershinin: well, yes, you may say so. Then the alphabet $\{1,2,\cdots,c\}$ clearly play only the role of providing the term $c^n$ at the denominator as the number of all possible words of length $n$, and the numerator is the number of words (length $n$) from the alphabet $\{1,\cdots,m\}$ that contain every character of that alphabet .